# Elixir not installed

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I just cloned an Elixir/Phoenix project but can't run any mix tasks. I keep getting `elixir 1.5.1 not installed`. I don't get it though since I have Elixir installed. If I run `elixir --version` from any other folder outside the project I can see I am running on Elixir 1.5.1. It's just inside this project that I keep getting the error that elixir is not installed.

What could be the problem? The contents of the mix.exs file look like this:
The project section

```
def project do
[
  app: :real_world,
  version: "0.0.1",
  elixir: "~> 1.5",
  elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env),
  compilers: [:phoenix, :gettext] ++ Mix.compilers,
  start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
  aliases: aliases(),
  deps: deps(),
  test_coverage: [tool: ExCoveralls],
]
end
```

And the deps section:

```
defp deps do
[
  {:phoenix, "~> 1.3.0"},
  {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.0"},
  {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.2"},
  {:postgrex, "~> 0.13.3"},
  {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
  {:proper_case, "~> 1.0.0"},
  {:cowboy, "~> 1.1"},
  {:comeonin, "~> 3.2"},
  {:guardian, "~> 0.14.5"},
  {:excoveralls, "~> 0.7", only: [:dev, :test]},
  {:credo, "~> 0.8.5", only: [:dev, :test]},
  {:ex_machina, "~> 2.0", only: :test},
  {:plug, "~> 1.0"},
  {:corsica, "~> 1.0"}
]
end
```

Comment: Show us: content of project’s `mix.exs` file, _exact_ error message you receive.

Comment: Do you have proper `PATH` set?

Comment: Just updated my question @mudasobwa

Comment: @PatNowak You mean the elixir path?

Comment: Also, by any chance do you have a file named like `.exenv-version` in the root directory of the project?

Comment: @mudasobwa ooh yeah. Inside it I see `1.5.1`

Comment: Just remove it and you are all set.

Comment: FYI: if you had had the exact error message posted straightway, the answer could be done yesterday.

Comment: I've done removed it but still getting `elixir 1.5.1 not installed` after running any mix command @mudasobwa

Comment: What `exenv versions` outputs?

Comment: Getting `command not found`. Seems I don't have `exenv` then

Comment: Eh. The issue is _definitely_ with a version manager. Try `kiex list` please. And `asdf list` as well. Also please share the output of `ls -la .` in the root project directory.

Comment: I don't have kiex too. Was just working on one elixir project so didn't have to worry about the versions. What should I install in this case? `asdf list` gives me `No plugin given` .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162407/discussion-between-christopher-vundi-and-mudasobwa).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>OK, for what it worth, I’d post an answer here.</sup>

One might have issues trying to run *foreign* code (e.g. cloned from *github*, or like,) if the elixir version manager file was originally committed into this repository (by the code owner,) and the code consumer *has the same version manager* installed, but without the exact version specified in this local file.

There are three popular version managers for Elixir/Erlang around. These are well [described here](https://elixirforum.com/t/elixir-version-managers/317).

`exenv` produces `.exenv-version` file, `asdf` produces `.tool-versions` and for `kiex` please read it’s documentation. The simplest way to make everything work would be to remove all these dot-files, but could in some rare cases break the build.

The best way would be to satisfy the dependency implied by the code owner. To do this, check what tool is actually used, and issue the following in the project root directory (the example below is for `asdf`, the rest should be similar):

```
$ asdf list elixir
1.5
```

read what is specified in the dot-file (`.tool-version` in this case):

```
$ cat .tool-version
erlang 20.0 
elixir 1.5.1
```

OK, we lack a version `1.5.1`. Install it with:

```
$ asdf install elixir 1.5.1
```

Now your project should run smoothly with the exact version implied by the code owner.

One installed, you can set a global or local version depending on what works for you.

Global:

```
$ asdf global elixir 1.5.1
```

Or local to the project:

```
$ asdf local elixir 1.5.1
```